How can i run Android Studio's project in multiple devices at the same time?
I want to run and test Android Studio's project at the same time in multiple devices for show
some Changes in UI related and also check chatting module.
can i get my solution by clicking this option in Android Studio ?


You tell us. What happens when you click it? Does it work?

Yes you can. Click run, change device, click run again, change device, and so on.

@RickyMo You are right. I can it but suppose i have 10 or more devices , so i need repeat it but i want Run project in all devices at the same time or single click..

If you want single click, you can white a shell script and use adb command to do it for every connected devices.

@RickyMo Can i get direct option in Android studio , so i don't need to follow any other steps.

You can click the drop down box of attached devices, then click "Select Multiple Devices"

Then select the devices you want and click "OK"

Now you can run on multiple devices with one click by clicking "Run"


Thank's a lot !! I got my perfect solution.
